# Crystal report: text over multiple details

Tags: crystal-reports

In crystal report 10 is it possible to have a text object placed across more than one detail? See below image...

[image: Example]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place image or text over multiple details is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a 100% sure but having worked with CR for past 3 years I don't think it's possible. Say what'll happen if I (somehow) have an image across two detail sections and then add a formula to hide one of the detail sections, I don't believe CR is intelligent enough to decide what to do
 Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about Crystal 10, but this works in 2008.  Put the text object you want to flow down the details in Details a and shift all the other details down so that Details a only contains the text object you want.  In the section expert for Details a, check "underlay following sections".  This will make the text flow across all the sections.  Need to be careful with the height of the detail, shorter details will cause the text to truncate.

[image]